# Sending Strongloop permissions to frontend

Tags: node.js, strongloop

I've been evaluating Strongloop (& Loopback) over the past couple of days. I've written a couple of helper endpoints for me to get information about my models in order to generate a CMS frontend for the REST API.

I've create a boot script that returns the public models that are in use, and a bit about them, as well as a couple of custom fields to do with the display of models etc. Here it is:

```
module.exports = function mountModelDiscoveryService(server) {

  server.get('/api/RemoteModules', function(req, res) {
    var models = server.models();

    var modelObject = [];

    models.forEach(function(Model) {

      if(Model.shared) {

        modelObject.push({
          name: Model.modelName,
          plural: (Model.settings.plural || Model.modelName),
          attributes: Model.definition.rawProperties,
          uri: (Model.settings.plural || Model.modelName).toLowerCase(),
          displaySettings: (Model.settings.display || {list: ["id", "title"]})
        })

      }

    });

    return res.send(modelObject);
  })

}
```

This is working well and I've been pleased with the progress. However, I'd like to be able to get a list of models (+ endpoints) that I have access to as the currently logged in user.

I've implemented the ACL stuff as the tutorial describes, and this correctly allows me or denies me access based on my current permission level, but this is only at the point of making the call - I was essentially wondering if anyone had tried to use the permissions system on the frontend - I'd like to hide certain elements if a user doesn't have access to create new objects, for example.

Do you think I should add some sort of property to this object that just returns a cut-down version of the ACL object with a complete list of what everyone can do? Is there an internal Loopback method I can use to achieve this result?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: This feature is not available out of the box, I suppose.